# Data from Ti.App.Properties.setString not persisting on Android after clearing the app from recent apps

Tags: android, titanium

I want to store the access token and email id of the user. But on Android after clearing the app from the recents list, the data gets cleared.
I have used setString to store the data:

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('access_token_key', access_token);
Ti.App.Properties.setString('email_id_key', email_id);
```

And fetch it using getString in app.js:

```
var access_token = Ti.App.Properties.getString('access_token_key');
var email_id = Ti.App.Properties.getString('email_id_key');
Ti.API.info("Access Token: " + access_token);
Ti.API.info("Email id: " + email_id);
```

This works perfectly on the iPhone, but on Android it displays null on running the app after clearing it from the recent apps menu.
How do I make it persist on Android also?
I am using the Titanium 3.1.3 SDK on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Are you sure that you are saving strings that are not empty? Have you tried `Ti.API.info(Ti.App.Properties.getString('access_token_key'));` immediately after storing to confirm it was stored?

Comment: Also make sure that access_token is string not array / object containing string.

Comment: It does print the access token after storing it.

Comment: It is working after converting it to a string. I guess it had an issue parsing if it was not a string on android. Thanks daniula.